# Need help to use Rating bar 

Tags: android, rating-system

I want to use rating bar in my android application.

My game has 10 levels I want to show the stars according to the score/time user scored per level. A screen will have 10 images for each level and 10 rating bars also.
Can any one help me with this. Please tell me the most effective solution for this problem.

There are 10 rating bars on a screen. Each independent of other.

Comment: Can't you use android's default RatingBar widget

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have gone through the [Google-developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html)

You can use,

```
<RatingBar   android:id="@+id/my_rating_bar"           
 ...             
style="@style/foodRatingBar" />
```

This [link](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/) will help you definetely, I have used this.